# Add key value headers with Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, key-value, request-headers

I am trying to add key value header before opening browser with ChromeDriver.
In order to add the headers not through code I use the browser extension called ModHeader
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

I tried the following code:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddAdditionalOption("key", "value");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32",options);
        driver.Url="https://someSite.com"
```

But this did not add the header.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to add a header

```
AddHeadersToBrowser.addHeaders(driver ,"{Key}", "{Value}");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. What is `AddHeadersToBrowser`? A variable? A static class? It is not present in the Selenium package.